# Kerning and long subscripts or superscripts

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, superscripts, kerning

For really long sub(super)scripts, does it look bad to decrease the kerning? i.e.

```
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{|x-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n} (x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx}=0
```

[image]

```
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{|x-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n} \kern-1cm(x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx}=0
```

[image]

```
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{|x-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n|} \kern-1.5cm(x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx}=0
```

[image]

Is it innappropriate to decrease the kerning? If not, which one looks best? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you need to INcrease not DEcrease the kerning. It's getting less and less readable. I'd put the integral sign on top of the path. You are using that space anyway

Comment: I actually did want to decrease the kerning, I did not think the white space between the integral sine and the integrand looked good. Your suggestion of moving the region of integration down is handled by @cmhughes answer.

Comment: I meant spacing out each operator, not gluing them together

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer the following. The important point is that there's no value to give: it uses the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools` and you decide at which place in the index you set it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{|x\mathrlap{-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n}} (x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx}=0 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of decent math, please remove the third vertical bar in the limit of integration. For the sake of good TeX code, please remove the curly braces that start before `\dfrac` and end before `=0`.

Comment: ah completely missed the third vertical bar! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Mico: I noticed it but didn't know if there was a seconf absolute value or not.

Comment: @Benjamin: Should it be `|sₙ|` or `sₙ` in the subscript?

Comment: @Mico was right its just $s_n$.

Comment: @Benjamin - please consider editing your posting to remove the third vertical bar in the limit of integration.

Comment: Just for you @Mico

Comment: @Benjamin - Awwwww

Answer (score 9):

Here's some more alternatives for reference:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ 
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{|x\mathrlap{-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n}} (x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx=0 
\]%
Using \verb!\limits!
\[ 
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int\limits_{|x\mathrlap{-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n}} (x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx=0 
\]%
Using a local definition, 
\[ 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{a_i} (x-\mu_i)^2f_i(x)dx=0 
\]%
where $a_i=|x-\mu_i|>\varepsilon s_n$

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the notation unambiguous, you may want to write `a_{i,n}` in the limit of integration, i.e.,  make `a` a function of both `i` *and* `n` (since it depends on `s_n`).

Comment: Good contribution, however, I like that mathrlap gives me some say in how much overlap there is.

Comment: @Benjamin - the first proposed solution *does* include an `\rlap` directive.

Comment: I was just explaining why I chose the other solution as "the" answer

Comment: @Mico nice idea - I might make the edit tomorrow :) Thanks also for the edit. Benjamin no worries, no need to explain - you, as the OP, choose which solution you think is most appropriate :)

Comment: I don't know if it's good math or not, but, if it is, I think placing the subscript below the integral provides better visual separation, making it look less crowded and easier to read. In the accepted answer, it looks less like a subscript and more like a second line. If you can't place the subscript below the integral sign, at least lower it and/or make it smaller.